# Unity Локальный мультиплеер

Tags: unity3d

Чисто из интереса хотел почитать как сделать простенький локальный мультиплеер на Unity. Из нормального нашёл только информацию про UNet, но ведь его уже выпилили? Какие есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В официальной документации к Юнити любой версии есть целая категория посвященная мультиплееру и нетворкингу:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/UNet.html

Слева сверху выбирается та версия, которая установлена у тебя на комп'ютере. Начни с изучения оф.документации, а там если возникнут КОНКРЕТНЫЕ проблемы - приходи с вопросами сюда.